# Mongo connection refused ECCONREFUSED

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I've got an application running in a docker container with docker compose. In the logs the container launches the db and has it listening on port 27017

Later in the app, having built the rest of the site, it attempts to connect to that db on that port and fails with ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

I think this might be quite a basic thing I'm not understanding here, but help would be greatly appreciated

```
Starting maroon_db_1
Recreating maroon_web_1
Attaching to maroon_db_1, maroon_web_1
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.114+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=e3a671f93ded
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.9
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian71
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.115+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.150+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.150+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.508+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.508+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.508+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.508+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.508+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.508+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.508+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.522+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.522+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
db_1   | 2016-08-22T10:50:27.543+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
web_1  |
web_1  | > mern-starter@2.0.0 bs /usr/src/app
web_1  | > npm run clean && npm run build && npm run build:server && npm run start:prod
web_1  |
web_1  |
web_1  | > mern-starter@2.0.0 clean /usr/src/app
web_1  | > rimraf dist
web_1  |
web_1  |
web_1  | > mern-starter@2.0.0 build /usr/src/app
web_1  | > cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js
web_1  |
web_1  | This preset is no longer necessary and can be replaced by the following:
web_1  |        presets: [
web_1  |            ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
web_1  |        ]
web_1  | Hash: afd840974c1321403cd5
web_1  | Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.8
web_1  | Time: 19804ms
web_1  |                                Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
web_1  |          app.edcea8de66cc864a67a5.js     375 kB       3  [emitted]  app
web_1  | bbaeb5f32b7042f0def39648a1d111b9.png    15.8 kB          [emitted]
web_1  |                            vendor.js     148 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor
web_1  |            1.b6dee935292b81563830.js    7.85 kB       1  [emitted]
web_1  |            2.6f2172bc1184d6c25200.js    1.55 kB       2  [emitted]
web_1  |                  chunk-manifest.json   97 bytes          [emitted]
web_1  |         app.edcea8de66cc864a67a5.css    3.04 kB       3  [emitted]  app
web_1  |         app.b6dee935292b81563830.css  708 bytes       1  [emitted]
web_1  |     app.b6dee935292b81563830.css.map  105 bytes       1  [emitted]
web_1  |     app.edcea8de66cc864a67a5.css.map  105 bytes       3  [emitted]  app
web_1  |                        manifest.json  508 bytes          [emitted]
web_1  |  [648] multi app 28 bytes {3} [built]
web_1  |  [649] multi vendor 40 bytes {0} [built]
web_1  |     + 655 hidden modules
web_1  | Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
web_1  |         + 2 hidden modules
web_1  | Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
web_1  |         + 2 hidden modules
web_1  | Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
web_1  |         + 2 hidden modules
web_1  | Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
web_1  |         + 2 hidden modules
web_1  | Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
web_1  |         + 2 hidden modules
web_1  | Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
web_1  |         + 3 hidden modules
web_1  |
web_1  | > mern-starter@2.0.0 build:server /usr/src/app
web_1  | > cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.server.js
web_1  |
web_1  | This preset is no longer necessary and can be replaced by the following:
web_1  |        presets: [
web_1  |            ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
web_1  |        ]
web_1  | babel-plugin-webpack-loader:
web_1  | To avoid caching errors you need to set BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 environment variable.
web_1  | More information at issue #36
web_1  | Hash: eaa3e07d940766fdd179
web_1  | Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.8
web_1  | Time: 74596ms
web_1  |            Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
web_1  | server.bundle.js  75.5 kB       0  [emitted]  main
web_1  |     + 63 hidden modules
web_1  |
web_1  | > mern-starter@2.0.0 start:prod /usr/src/app
web_1  | > cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js
web_1  |
web_1  | was local
web_1  | server config { mongoURL: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mern-starter',
web_1  |   port: 3030 }
web_1  | MERN is running on port: 3030! Build something amazing!
web_1  | Please make sure Mongodb is installed and running!
web_1  |
web_1  | /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
web_1  |         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
web_1  |                                       ^
web_1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
web_1  |     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
web_1  |     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
web_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
web_1  |
web_1  | npm ERR! Linux 4.4.15-moby
web_1  | npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "start:prod"
web_1  | npm ERR! node v4.0.0
web_1  | npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
web_1  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
web_1  | npm ERR! mern-starter@2.0.0 start:prod: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js`
web_1  | npm ERR! Exit status 1
web_1  | npm ERR!
web_1  | npm ERR! Failed at the mern-starter@2.0.0 start:prod script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js'.
web_1  | npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mern-starter package,
web_1  | npm ERR! not with npm itself.
web_1  | npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
web_1  | npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js
web_1  | npm ERR! You can get their info via:
web_1  | npm ERR!     npm owner ls mern-starter
web_1  | npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
web_1  |
web_1  | npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
web_1  | npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
web_1  |
web_1  | npm ERR! Linux 4.4.15-moby
web_1  | npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "bs"
web_1  | npm ERR! node v4.0.0
web_1  | npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
web_1  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
web_1  | npm ERR! mern-starter@2.0.0 bs: `npm run clean && npm run build && npm run build:server && npm run start:prod`
web_1  | npm ERR! Exit status 1
web_1  | npm ERR!
web_1  | npm ERR! Failed at the mern-starter@2.0.0 bs script 'npm run clean && npm run build && npm run build:server && npm run start:prod'.
web_1  | npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mern-starter package,
web_1  | npm ERR! not with npm itself.
web_1  | npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
web_1  | npm ERR!     npm run clean && npm run build && npm run build:server && npm run start:prod
web_1  | npm ERR! You can get their info via:
web_1  | npm ERR!     npm owner ls mern-starter
web_1  | npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
web_1  |
web_1  | npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
web_1  | npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
maroon_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you exposed port 27017 for MongoDB in docker-compose.yml? However if you don't want to expose MongoDB to internet (the recommended way), you can use Docker's internal DNS to connect MongoDB (example of docker-compose.yml):

`mongodb:
  image: mongo:3.2
web:
  build: .
  environment:
    - MONGODB_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/mern-starter`

Then in your application you can use `MONGODB_URL` environment variable to connect MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks, it was that. I had the env variable in my code at one point and then deleted it, opting for a straight connection string.